# what is the purpose of 'NULL' in processing loops?

Tags: r

```
sqr = seq(1, 100, by=2)
sqr.squared = NULL
for (n in 1:50)
{
  sqr.squared[n] = sqr[n]^2
}
```

I came accross the loop above, for a beginner this was simple enough.  To further understand r what was the precise purpose of the second line?  For my research I gather it has something to do with resetting the vector.  If someone could elaborate it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sqr.squared <- NULL
```

is one of many ways initialize the empty vector `sqr.squared` prior to running it through a loop. In general, when the length of the resulting vector is known, it is much better practice to allocate the vector's length. So here,

```
sqr.squared <- vector("integer", 50)
```

would be much better practice. And faster too. This way you are not building the new vector in the loop.  But since `^` is vectorized, you could also simply do

```
sqr[1:50] ^ 2
```

and ditch the loop all together.

Comment: sorry, still to slow to copy.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  What is too slow to copy?

Comment: Need to put the time in to comprehend everything.

Comment: Need to put the time in to comprehend everything.  My first gist is that the code is not merely assigning , i.e. a = sqr[n]^2.  But rather doing, sqr.squared[n] = sqr[n]^2, that is sub setting.  Therefore this asked to sub setting..  (this is the first thing I need to grasp).  Then the substitute code, sqr.squared <- vector("integer", 50), .. all in all the basic I understand is that is: initializing the vector one way or the other.  Then I am thinking initializing is required(why) since this in the loop.  Slow because merely reading isn't enough to learn, I need to put in the man hours.  Thx

Answer (score 3):

Another way to think about it is to remember that everything in r is a function call, and functions need input (usually).

say you calculated `y` and want to store that value somewhere. You can do `x <- y` without initializing an `x` object (r does this for you unlike in other languages, c for example), but say you want to store it in a specific place in x.

So note that `<-` (or `=` in your example) is a function

```
y <- 1

x[2] <- y
# Error in x[2] <- y : object 'x' not found
```

This is a different function than  `<-`. Since you want to put `y` at `x[2]`, you need the function `[<-`

```
`[<-`(x, 2, y)
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

But this still doesn't work because we need the object `x` to use this function, so initialize `x` to something.

```
(x <- numeric(5))
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0

# and now use the function
`[<-`(x, 2, y)
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0
```

This **pre**fix notation is easier for computers to parse (eg, `+ 1 1`) but harder for humans (me at least), so we prefer **in**fix notation (eg, `1 + 1`). R makes such functions easier to use `x[2] <- y` rather than how I did above.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is correct, when you assign a NULL value to a variable, the purpose is to initialize a vector. In many cases, when you are working checking numbers or with different types of variables, you will need to set NULL this arrays, matrix, etc.

For example, in you want to create a some type of element, in some cases you will need to put something inside them. This is the purpose of to use NULL. In addition, sometimes you will require NA instead of NULL.